# How do I unbind the SPC key from a pdf-viewer window and use evil leader key instead?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keymap, use-package, pdf-tools

How can I unbind the SPC keybinding from a pdf-view-mode window and use the evil leader key instead?

This is what I have currently:

```
  (use-package pdf-tools
    :ensure t
    :config
    (pdf-tools-install)
    (with-eval-after-load 'pdf-view 
        (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "SPC") nil)))
```

Describe-key shows the SPC key is being bound to "pdf-view-scroll-up-or-next-page"

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the define-key location to the mode-hook you want to use like this?

```lisp
(add-hook 'evil-leader-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "SPC") nil)))
```

Comment: I don't use the 'evil-leader' package, is there a way to achieve this without this package? I have evil-collection installed.